# How can i get integer value from this characters?

Tags: java, type-conversion

"I want to insert characters through user input. Then i need to get a output a integer value similar to each character?

ex : input -

```
thr#e hun#red forty five t#ou#and two hundred th#rty f#ur
```

output -

```
345234
```

I've tried this code.' but it show some error messages.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String N = input.next();
    int result = Integer.parseInt(N);
    System.out.println(result);

}
```

}

Comment: Integer.parseInt will not do this kind of complicated logic for you.  You will have to write code to figure out all these details yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If it was my project I would try **changing the sharp character** *(#)* **to all the english alphabet's characters** and see **which one fits the best to the word** and then **change the output to letters**.

**Example code:** *(change input to letters names)*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // input o#e tw# thr#e

    char[] alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    String[] numbers = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "zero"};
    String input = "o#e tw# thr#e";

    String[] words = input.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { // reads one by one the words
        for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) { checks if the character[j] fits the word
            for (int k = 0; k < numbers.length; k++) { // checks if the numbers contain that string
                if (numbers[k].equalsIgnoreCase(words[i].replace('#', alphabet[j])))
                    words[i] = numbers[k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```